# GUI not updating after a remove, revalidate, and repaint

Tags: java, swing

In the program I'm creating, I'm showing a local queue on a GUI, and letting the user have the option to click a button to remove the top element of the queue, thus removing it from the queue and the panel. When I try to remove it from the panel and "refresh" the panel, it only works once.

---

Screenshot of the panel:
[image: Screenshot of the panel]

---

Example of the situation:

1) Queue of 5 elements is created and shown on the panel

2) User clicks button to remove top of queue

- Top of queue is deleted and successfully removed from the screen

3) User clicks button to remove top of queue again

- Top of queue is deleted but does not remove from the screen

(Side note: it only adds to my resolvedTickets_ panel once as well)

---

Here is a code snippet; I can provide more if need be:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if("removeFromQueue".equals(evt.getActionCommand())){

        System.out.println("removeFromQueue button clicked");

        if(empty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Queue is empty! Good work.");
            return;
        }

        // Removes top of queue from screen
        MainFrame.activeQueue_.remove(queue.get(0));

        // Updates UI
        MainFrame.activeQueue_.revalidate();
        MainFrame.activeQueue_.repaint();

        resolved.add(queue.get(0)); // Adds to resolved tickets

        MainFrame.resolvedTickets_.add(resolved.get(resolved_COUNT));
        resolved_COUNT++;

        deleteFirst(); // Deletes from queue
    }
}
```

The `deleteFirst()` method:

```
public void deleteFirst() {
    if (empty()) {
        return;
    }

    if (front.equals(null)) {
        rear = null;
    }

    front = front.getNext();
    COUNT--;
}
```

---

Thank you for any help and / or advice in advance.

Comment: _"Another thing to look out for is that the repaint() command doesn't really force the panel to repaint right away... it just kind of says that the panel should be repainted at the next earliest opportunity. Multiple repaint requests right after another may be merged into a single actual repaint. I don't think this is a problem, because you noticed how putting a 1 ms pause made the animation smoother... without the pause all the repaint requests were merged into 1 and the animation just jumped to the last state."_  12th post http://www.coderanch.com/t/335633/GUI/java/JPanel-repainting-properly

Comment: Hmm, I see @Vahx. Do you know how to proceed with a safe way to pause? Using Thread.sleep(value); surrounded by a try/catch does not work before repaint(); is called

Comment: Mind showing your `deleteFirst()` method to ensure the element is being removed from `queue` when you click the button?

Comment: Sure @VinceEmigh. I'm pretty sure it is though as my if statement checking if it's empty works. Here it is though: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LLjVzh6j (Code doesn't look nice as a comment apparently)

Comment: I do not see where you do `queue.remove` in that method; is the item actually being removed from the queue?

Comment: @VinceEmigh Yep! It skips over the first node, making `front.getNext()` the new head of the queue

Comment: But you are removing `queue.get(0)`, not `front`. It doesn't seem as if you affect the positions in the `queue`

Comment: @VinceEmigh Ah, bad code conventions on my part. I didn't realize as I was writing it. `queue` is actually a LinkedList<JTextArea> comprised of my queue elements that I manually created for the GUI. The full class can be seen here if you'd like: http://pastebin.com/Yvp65Sfy My bad. I'll rename that right away.

Comment: `empty()` should not rely on the front being null; it should specify that the queue is actually empty (logic flaw). As for your current problem, I see that you wanna do something like `MainFrame.activeQueue_.remove(front)`, yet you do `MainFrame.activeQueue_.remove(queue.get(0))`. Like I said before, you don't seem to be modifying the positions of the items in the queue; you're attempting to remove the same item every time. You need to remove the item from the `queue`, so the next item can shift into position `0`. **Try putting `queue.removeFirst()` or `queue.remove(0)` in `deleteFirst()`**

Comment: @VinceEmigh You rock. While it wouldn't be `front`, as that is not related directly to the GUI, removing the first element of the linked list (particularly why I chose linked lists) puts the second element as the first. So a simple `queue.remove(0);` (which I renamed to `listOfQueue`) in my action performed did the trick. I thought it was related to my `repaint()` this whole time. Thanks for stepping me in the right direction. Could we move this to an answer somehow so I can mark the thread as answered?

Comment: No problem :) I suggest fixing up your design so your list stores nodes, and each node has a text area. When you access a node, grab the text area from it to remove

Comment: Sounds good! I'll look into that after I finish some modifications. Thanks again @VinceEmigh